# Вебхук в ВК или возможна оптимизация LongPoll?

Tags: java, vkontakte-api, long-poll

Делаю клиент VK в виде бота для Telegram. Сделал обмен сообщениями в разные стороны, чаты. Вроде все хорошо. Но постоянное дергание VK LongPoll забивает канал дико и часто начинаю получать тайм-аут.
Суть вопроса: можно ли как-то реализовать **веб хуки** для VK (например, как в Telegram: https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#setwebhook
или есть какие-то варианты оптимизации **LongPoll**? (Необязательно именно VK LongPoll, наверняка есть универсальные методы..)

Comment: Вообще на нормальных сайтах уже давно сделали вебсокеты, но ВК не из таких

Comment: @andreymal и то правда. Просто я тупо физически не могу нормально получать обновления длительное время, ибо Лонг весь канал превращает в неизвестно что...

Comment: Можно юзать аналог вебхука, называется [Callback API](https://vk.com/dev/callback_api), но применимо только для сообщений сообщества. Для сообщений пользователя только LongPoll.

Comment: @terron вот и я про тоже... А как его хотя бы более экономным сделать?